# Keeping track of how many times a node has been visited

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I have been researching this topic for a while. I have yet to come to a solid conclusion.

How would you keep track of how many times a node has been visited in a Doubly Linked List?

For example:

Let's say we enter a few nodes and each node holds a value of type char.

The user types in the values to the node that they want to visit.

User enters : 'b', 'b', 'c' 'b', 'a', ' a'.

Now 'b' has been visited three times.

Now since b is the most visited node, you want to move that node to the front.

Moving a node to the front is easy, but I have no idea how one would keep track of a node.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what's the larger problem you're trying to solve here? are you sure that a doubly linked list is the right data structure for this?

Comment: how would you keep track of how often something is used in the real world? You'd add an inventory tracking system...

Comment: @ acushner Well, yes I am sure only because I have to use it. What I am doing is making a spell checker program. The user enters in their sentence and my program corrects it if it is misspelled.  I am trying to make it that the most visited words are sent to front for quicker access. More or less a self-organizing doubly linked list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a count field in your node as follows:-

```
struct node
{
char alpha;
int count;
struct node *next;
}
```

Also, define a constructor where you would set count to 0. You have to continuously check for count to sort linked list at every input.

One thing for sure is that this will be very poor choice of data structure for this.

EDITED IN RESPONSE TO THE COMMENT:-

Try mapping it with `std::priority_queue` where priority will be the count of the word. Choose max-heap for implementing this. OR you can also use `std::multimap<int, string>` ( int being count and string being your word) for simplicity.

Comment: I know, it is a poor choice. I am being forced to use a doubly linked list though. I see where you are going with this and it definitely helps. Thank you very much.

Comment: The only thing that confuses me is calling the count. I get that you would initialize count to 0 for each node. But, when you increase each time it is visited would you just say Node->count++; Is that legal?

Comment: Whenever you create a new node just set count to 1 and whenever visiting increment it's value

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again, but how would you increment its value? That is the only thing I do not understand. I may have edited my above question after you initially saw it, my apologies.